# jQuery does not delete user info

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php page that uses a jQuery to confirm before deleting data, Infact when I click delete it doesnt do anything the link doesnt do anything, I tried my efforts still nothing happens, please assist me

my code
teacher.php

```
    <?php
    require_once('../auth.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Silay Institute</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!--sa poip up-->
<link href="src/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="src/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loadingImage : 'src/loading.gif',
        closeImage   : 'src/closelabel.png'
      })
    })
  </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="febe/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<script src="argiepolicarpio.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style>
#mainhhh {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 8px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4E707C;
    font: 11px "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 5em auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1000px;
}
#mainhhh h1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0092C8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #007DAB;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #007DAB;
}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainhhh">
<h1>
<a id="addq" href="index.php" title="click to enter homepage" style="background-image:url('../images/out.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; padding: 3px 12px 12px; margin-right: 10px;"></a>
<label for="filter">Filter</label> <input type="text" name="filter" value="" id="filter" />
    <a rel="facebox" href="addteacher.php" id="addq">Add Teacher</a>

</h1>

        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="resultTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th  style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7"> Name </th>
                    <th>ID Number</th>
                    <th>Work</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Birthday</th>
                    <th>Advisory</th>
                    <th> Action </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                include('../connect.php');
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teacher");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo '<tr class="record">';
                        echo '<td  style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7">'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['mname'].' '.$row['lname'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td><div align="left">'.$row['idnumber'].'</div></td>';
                        echo '<td><div align="left">'.$row['work'].'</div></td>';
                        echo '<td><div align="left">'.$row['gender'].'</div></td>';
                        echo '<td><div align="left">'.$row['status'].'</div></td>';
                        echo '<td><div align="left">'.$row['bday'].'</div></td>';
                        echo '<td><div align="left">';
                        $sdsd=$row['idnumber'];
                        $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `teacher` JOIN `advisory` ON `advisory`.`tid`=`teacher`.`idnumber`");
                            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results))
                                {
                                echo $rows['level'].' section '.$rows['section'];
                                }
                        echo '</div></td>';
                        echo '<td><div align="center"><a rel="facebox" href="editprofile.php?id='.$row['id'].'" title="Click To Edit">Edit Profile</a> | <a href="#" id="'.$row['id'].'" class="delbutton" title="Click To Delete">delete</a></div></td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                ?> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>  
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {


$(".delbutton").click(function(){

//Save the link in a variable called element
var element = $(this);

//Find the id of the link that was clicked
var del_id = element.attr("id");

//Built a url to send
var info = {'id': del_id};

 if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
          {

 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "deleteteacher.php",
   data: info,
   success: function(){

   }
 });
         $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");

 }

return false;

});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

deleteteacher.php

```
<?php

// This is a sample code in case you wish to check the username from a mysql db table
include('../connect.php');
if($_GET['id'])
{
$id = intval($_GET['id']); 
 $sql = "delete from teacher where id='$id'";
 mysql_query( $sql);
}

?>
```

Comment: Ew, nested `mysql_fetch_*` loops... OHGOD MYSQL INJECTION!

Comment: Change your query to this: ``SELECT * FROM `teacher` JOIN `advisory` ON `advisory`.`tid`=`teacher`.`idnumber` `` - it's a lot more efficient than nested query loops!

Comment: And for the love of all that is good, [sanitize your inputs](http://xkcd.com/327/)! I cannot emphasize this enough. In this case, try `$id = intval($_GET['id']);`

Comment: Try `deleteteacher.php?id=0'%20OR%20TRUE%20OR%20'`

Little bobby tables :)

Comment: And another thing, [don't use GET for anything that changes the state of the server](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/08/08/hey-you-deleted-my-files/) ESPECIALLY when deleting stuff. Use `POST` instead.

Comment: Too much code for a little problem. Please re-write your example from scratch with as little code as necessary to reproduce the issue. Then provide reference to argue what it should does and explain what it does instead. Then ask your question.

Comment: first backup the database than try `deleteteacher.php?id='a';DROP TABLE teacher ; --` can do the magic ... and after completing show either escape/sanitize query or better use prepared statements and i recommended use of PDO

Comment: What @kolink said: Also because it is very easy to 'trick' an authorized person to go to load a certain page (e.g. forum picture that is redirected to Paul Dixon's url).

Comment: @NullPoiиteя That won't work, because `mysql_*` functions don't allow you to run multiple queries. Pretty sure that feature was implemented to prevent such an attack. Of course, that still leaves Paul's input which would equally destroy the table.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, you should send a JSON object as data; its means you should make a dictionary, not just an assignment. When you write `$_GET['id']` compiler searches for an element in the data dictionary with key "id" to returns its value; but since you don't send a dictionary structured data, it returns NULL and of course nothing will happen.

You should write something like this in your delete function:

`var info = {'id': del_id};`

Comment: I have two suggestions for you: 1- Use POST method; 2- Use this line to interact with database: `$sql = "delete from teacher where id='" + $id + "'";` (Since you used intval `$id` is an integer and I think you should use concatenation)